# IIS 7.5 URL Rewirte https

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

Previously I was using URL Rewrite.

1) http://example.com/ : root url rewrite

```
            <rule name="PC rewrite main" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?example.(net|com)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/main/default.asp" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
```

2) http://example.com/product/12345 : product url rewrite

```
            <rule name="Product PC" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^product/([0-9]+)*\/?$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/goods/detail.asp?gno={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

It was working fine, but I applied https and there are too many redirects.

3) https

```
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^off$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

I do not know what's wrong. Please let me know

Comment: Because people usually check `{HTTPS}` https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: I changed {HTTPS} check. but same result "too many redirect"

Comment: Can you use FRT to check further? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Things like Cloudflare can also cause such if you misconfigure it.

Comment: REWRITE_DISABLED_KERNEL_CACHE Warning. Currently the rewrite rule acts as a redirect, so I will try to remove the module and reinstall it.